# Sitecore Forced password change

Tags: asp.net-membership, sitecore

I need to implement such a feature . 
It need to work so that x days after you last changed your password, then when you login you get a message that says, your password has expired, please enter a new password and confirm the new password

Do you have any ideas/suggestions how to do that in the proper way?

Comment: Are you checking CMS users or website users?

Comment: Hello I'm checking Cms Users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add your own processor as a first processor of `loggingin` pipeline with `Process` method:

```c#
public void Process(LoggingInArgs args)
{
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(args.Username);
    if (user != null)
    {
        DateTime date = user.LastPasswordChangedDate;
        if ((DateTime.Now - date).TotalDays > maxDaysWithoutPasswordChange)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/passwordchangepage");
        }
    }
}
```

This will redirect all the users that require password change to the `/passwordchangepage` url. On this page create a form for old password and new password.

On submitting the form execute password change:

```c#
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(username);
user.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);
```

Answer (score 3):

I used [this](http://sitecorejunkie.com/2013/06/08/enforce-password-expiration-in-the-sitecore-cms/) post to implement the same functionality in a recent project.

It gives you a full run through of the code required and how to create the config file to patch the new `Pipeline`. Also creates parameters for the password reset page and the x days to expire passwords.

```
public class CheckPasswordExpiration
    {
        private TimeSpan TimeSpanToExpirePassword { get; set; }
        private string ChangePasswordPageUrl { get; set; }

        public void Process(LoggingInArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
            if (!IsEnabled())
            {
                return;
            }

            MembershipUser user = GetMembershipUser(args);
            if (HasPasswordExpired(user))
            {
                WebUtil.Redirect(ChangePasswordPageUrl);
            }
        }

        private bool IsEnabled()
        {
            return IsTimeSpanToExpirePasswordSet() && IsChangePasswordPageUrlSet();
        }

        private bool IsTimeSpanToExpirePasswordSet()
        {
            return TimeSpanToExpirePassword > default(TimeSpan);
        }

        private bool IsChangePasswordPageUrlSet()
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ChangePasswordPageUrl);
        }

        private static MembershipUser GetMembershipUser(LoggingInArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(args.Username, "args.Username");
            return Membership.GetUser(args.Username, false);
        }

        private bool HasPasswordExpired(MembershipUser user)
        {
            return user.LastPasswordChangedDate.Add(TimeSpanToExpirePassword) <= DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For my particular situation the customer did not want to use the sitecore password reset tool. I created a visual studio solution of my sitecore web site and made a branded change password page. Once I had the page I placed the following in the Global.asax of my VS solution.

```
  protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
          // Get the user as they log in
          MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();

          // if the user is not blank
          // and the password expiry date is less than the password policy expiration date
          // and the user is not directly calling the change password page
          if (user != null && user.LastPasswordChangedDate.Date.AddDays(90) < DateTime.Now.Date && !Request.Path.EndsWith("/layouts/changepw.aspx"))
          {
              // Then transfer to the change password page
              Server.Transfer("~/layouts/changepw.aspx");
          }
      }
  }
```

Once they hit the change password page I checked to see if they were sent from the login page or from within the web site. Depending on the URL referrer I displayed the appropriate "your password will soon expire" message.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore's security model is based on ASP.NET one, which actually does not have such functionality as well. So this looks more like a customization of common ASP.NET functionality, not actually related to Sitecore. However I can provide you with some suggestions on how to implement this.

You can create 2 properties for user profile: one property to expiration duration(or setting in the web.config), another to keep date of last password updating. Then you should change your authentication logic a bit.

First of all, before user is authenticated, you should check values of the new custom fields for the user specified on the login form. Then if the password is expired ask the user to change it - redirect him to a page with some form containing 3 fields: "old password", "new password" and "confirm new password".

Having these 3 values you can change user password using appropriate method of MemberhipUser class. After the password is changed you can authenticate user.